# Can Thinking Sphinx delayed delta use a named delayed_job queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

We need to have separate queues for different types of jobs. One of them is Thinking Sphinx delayed deltas. We could keep using the default queue but we rather use a specifically named queue. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. In thinking_sphinx.yml add:

```
development:
  .
  .
  delayed_job_queue: "<name>"
```

Repeat for other environments.